# Path of the image for "EMAIL" share in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have implemented slide function for images and now need to set current page as body of the Email and share it in phonegap. i'm able to send the email but not with the image,  can i set the first image as current page and set the path? please help me to give the right path for the Sliding image.

here's my java intent code

```
private void doSendIntent(String subject, String text) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);           
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0);      
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"file_path");
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(path.getAbsolutePath())));
}
```

Had implemented image swipe in javascript.

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
     <img src="images/v2.jpg" >
     <div class="wrapper">
     <button class="button" id="Email" onclick="share()">Hello</button>         </div> 
   </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
    <img src="images/v.jpg" >
   <div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button" id="Email" onclick="share()">Hello</button>
  </div>                
  </div>
  <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>

 <script>
 var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
  pagination: '.pagination',
 paginationClickable: true
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+filepath.jpg)));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have 10 images in swipe, how to give path for all the 10 images? @Amit Prajapati

Comment: images are in assets folder @Amit Prajapati